# How to condition a statement in Ajax to insert or not once it has been true or false? CodeIgniter PHP

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have already successfully executed the inserting of data, additionally if it has existing data then it will not be inserted.

But the problem is, even though the data is duplicate and not inserted, the alert box still says that the data has been successfully imported, so how can I fix this and change its statement?

How can I return the statement false and show alert once the data is duplicate and return true to show alert once it has been inserted without existing data.

Controller:

```
function import()
{
    if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    {
        $path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
        foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
        {
            $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
            for($row=16; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
            {
                $studentID = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $name = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $grade = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue();
                $subject = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, 8)->getValue();
                $slug = url_title($subject);

                if($name != null){
                    $data[$row] = array(
                    'studentID'  => $studentID,
                    'name'  => $name,
                    'grade' => $grade,
                    'subject' => $slug
                    );
                }
            
            }
        }
        
            $subj = array('subject' => $slug);
            // This is where I tried to condition the proper statement of the alert
            if($data == true){
                $this->loading_model->insert($data,$subj);
                echo 'Data Imported successfully';
            }else{
                echo 'Invalid: Data has already been imported';
            }
            
    } 
}
```

Model:

```
function insert($data,$subj)
{
    
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_college_grades', array('subject' => $subj['subject']));
    if ($query->num_rows() == 0) 
    {
      return $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_college_grades', $data);
    }
    else 
    {
      return false;
    }

}
```

Ajax:

```
$('#import_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
   url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>loadings/import",
   method:"POST",
   data:new FormData(this),
   contentType:false,
   cache:false,
   processData:false,
   success:function(data){
        $('#file').val('');
        load_data();
        alert(data);
   }
  })
 });
```

Comment: Is it right that you are declaring `$subj = array('subject' => $slug);` after your loop -- you want it to only hold the last iteration's data???

Comment: @mickmackusa - I've used it because I need to get the data and use it in the model. Am I wrong about it? without it I cannot fetch the subjects needed.

Comment: In your `insert()` method, you have written `array('subject' => $subj['subject'])`, but your controller is already passing `$subj = array('subject' => $slug);`.  So you are effectively using `['subject' => ['subject' => $slug];`, right?  I think you need to break your script down and check the data at different checkpoints to see if it contains exactly what you expect as it passes through your MVC layers.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to embrace the CI way of accessing `$_FILES` data? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16345875/2943403  Have you checked your server logs for errors?